# How can i use looping from 2 file txt?

Tags: arrays, loops, shell, for-loop, while-loop

I have 2 file .txt that i want to use for looping backup database.

File 1 is database name = **DB_NAME.txt**

```
db_abc
db_def
```

File 2 is table name = **TB_NAME.txt**

```
tb_123
tb_456
tb_789
```

i want to use it to

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --compact --no-create-info -u<user> -p<pass> -h<ip> ${DB_NAME} ${TB_NAME} > /home/backup/backup_data/data_${DB_NAME}_${TB_NAME}_$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").sql
```

What i want is that loop's script, running like this

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --compact --no-create-info -u<user> -p<pass> -h<ip> **db_abc tb_123** > /home/backup/backup_data/data_**db_abc_tb_123**_$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").sql

/usr/bin/mysqldump --compact --no-create-info -u<user> -p<pass> -h<ip> **db_abc tb_456** > /home/backup/backup_data/data_**db_abc_tb_456**_$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").sql

/usr/bin/mysqldump --compact --no-create-info -u<user> -p<pass> -h<ip> **db_abc tb_123** > /home/backup/backup_data/data_**db_abc_tb_123**_$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").sql

/usr/bin/mysqldump --compact --no-create-info -u<user> -p<pass> -h<ip> **db_def tb_123** > /home/backup/backup_data/data_**db_def_tb_123**_$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").sql

/usr/bin/mysqldump --compact --no-create-info -u<user> -p<pass> -h<ip> **db_def tb_456** > /home/backup/backup_data/data_**db_def_tb_456**_$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").sql

/usr/bin/mysqldump --compact --no-create-info -u<user> -p<pass> -h<ip> **db_def tb_123** > /home/backup/backup_data/data_**db_def_tb_123**_$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").sql
```

I already tried using array like this, but i didn't get like what i want

```
#!/bin/bash

l_db="/home/scripts/backup/DB_NAME.txt";
l_tb="/home/scripts/backup/TB_NAME.txt";

declare -a database=(`cat ${l_db}`)
declare -a table=(`cat ${l_tb}`)

for DB in "${database[@]}"; do
    /usr/bin/mysqldump --compact --no-create-info -u<user> -p<pass> -ip ${DB} ${table[$i]} > /home/backup/backup_data/data_${DB}_${table[$i]}_$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").sql
done
```

I hope someone know how to solve my problem, and want to share his/her knowledge. please

Comment: Without testing your code, it seems like you're almost there. Why not add another loop inside the first? ie. `for TB in "${table[@]}" ; do` .. and then just the one command `/usr/bin/mysqldump` referencing both `$DB` and `$TB`. Note  you never defint `$i` in your existing code.Good luck.

Comment: ahh... finally I got what I wanted. and it turns out the solution is in front of my eyes. thanks for the enlightenment bro, it's helped me alot.